# Mysql 5.5 cannot reconnect after a several minutes

Tags: mysql

I used mysql 5.5 in my project and encontered a problem that I can't solve. I googled but without result. My client can connect the server normally however after a while about 10 minutes the connection lost. The client would reconnect the server but it hangs up and never return a connection. I tried with two kinds of clients: The native mysql console client and the mysql workbench and same result. Here are some details:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show variables like "%timeout%";
+----------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name              | Value    |
+----------------------------+----------+
| connect_timeout            | 10       |
| deadlock_timeout_long      | 50000000 |
| deadlock_timeout_short     | 10000    |
| delayed_insert_timeout     | 300      |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout   | 50       |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout | OFF      |
| interactive_timeout        | 28800    |
| lock_wait_timeout          | 31536000 |
| net_read_timeout           | 30       |
| net_write_timeout          | 60       |
| slave_net_timeout          | 3600     |
| thread_pool_idle_timeout   | 60       |
| wait_timeout               | 28800    |
+----------------------------+----------+
```

so the `wait_timeout`and `interactive_timeout` seems normal and I can't get some other logs about the problem.

**EDIT:**  I find this problem only occures when I connect the server via remote clients. The local client doesn't have the problem.

Comment: Have you tried forcing a close before reconnecting?

Comment: I think the problem may exists on the server side. And the client can't force to close the connection. Just about serveral minutes later I issue an sql and then it hangs forever!